# undefined method `ensure_initialized' rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have `composite_primary_keys` gem install and used with Rails 4.2.0.rc2, and I keep getting a

```
undefined method `ensure_initialized' for #<ActiveRecord::AttributeSet:0x007fcb319ed988>
```

error from this [line](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys/blob/ar_4.2.x/lib/composite_primary_keys/core.rb#L6):

```
  Array(self.class.primary_key).each {|key| @attributes.ensure_initialized(key)}
```

Stack:

```
/Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/composite_primary_keys-0a8061943732/lib/composite_primary_keys/core.rb:6:in `block in init_internals'
/Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/composite_primary_keys-0a8061943732/lib/composite_primary_keys/core.rb:6:in `each'
/Users/mmahalwy/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bundler/gems/composite_primary_keys-0a8061943732/lib/composite_primary_keys/core.rb:6:in `init_internals'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc2) lib/active_record/core.rb:274:in `initialize'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc2) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc2) lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:61:in `new'
delayed_job (4.0.2) lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:29:in `enqueue'
activejob (4.2.0.rc2) lib/active_job/queue_adapters/delayed_job_adapter.rb:18:in `enqueue'
activejob (4.2.0.rc2) lib/active_job/enqueuing.rb:71:in `block in enqueue'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:190:in `block in simple'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:338:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:338:in `block (2 levels) in simple'
activejob (4.2.0.rc2) lib/active_job/logging.rb:14:in `call'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by a [bug](https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys/pull/263) in the version you are using for the gem. update the gem:

```
bundle update composite_primary_keys
```

and try again.